# Trying to figure out how to do a dynamic sql pivot table with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I am still a beginner with T-SQL have what is a relatively simple select statement with a few joins. I am trying to put it into a dynamic pivot table. The purpose of this statement is to show non-profit services and their outcomes, with new and old outcomes just being pairs of different words of the same data.

```
SELECT Service.Name,
OutcomeIndicator."Desc" AS OutcomeDesc,
NewOutcomeIndicator.Description As NewOutcomeDesc
FROM service 
FULL OUTER JOIN OutcomeIndicator ON ServiceOutcomeIndicator.OutcomeIndicatorID=OutcomeIndicator.OutcomeIndicatorID
FULL OUTER JOIN NewOutcomeIndicator ON NewOutcomeIndicatorMapping.NewOutcomeIndicatorID=NewOutcomeIndicator.NewOutcomeIndicatorID
```

However, when I run this statement, it obviously returns every row, including multiple values for the ServiceName since each service can have multiple Outcomes/NewOutcome pairings.

```
+-------------+----------------+------------------+
| ServiceName |  OutcomeDesc1  | NewOutcomeDesc1  |
+-------------+----------------+------------------+
| Service34   | OutcomeDesc14  | NewOutcomeDesc14 |
| Service34   | OutcomeDesc12  | NewOutcomeDesc12 |
| Service35   | OutcomeDesc4   | NewOutcomeDesc4  |
| Service44   | OutcomeDesc80  | NewOutcomeDesc80 |
| Service44   | OutcomeDesc99  | NewOutcomeDesc99 |
| Service51   | OutcomeDesc50  | NewOutcomeDesc50 |
```

For reporting purposes, since this is being copied into excel, I would want something more like this:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| ServiceName  |  OutcomeDesc1   | NewOutcomeDesc1   |  OutcomeDesc2   | NewOutcomeDesc2   | OutcomeDesc3 |  NewOutcomeDesc3    |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| Service34    | OutcomeDesc14   | NewOutcomeDesc14  | OutcomeDesc12   | NewOutcomeDesc12  |              |                     |
| Service35    | OutcomeDesc4    | NewOutcomeDesc4   |                 |                   |              |                     |
| Service44    | OutcomeDesc80   | NewOutcomeDesc80  | OutcomeDesc99   | NewOutcomeDesc99  |              |                     |
| Service51    | OutcomeDesc50   | NewOutcomeDesc50  |                 |                   |              |                     |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Any idea on how I can change my sql statement to do this? I can statically define the number of columns, since I know there aren't more than 3 outcomes per Service.

I understand how to do a static pivot table in sql,but because there are hundreds of services and outcomes, I can't define the logic of statistically assigning each of the Service values to a column. Dynamic pivot tables are a little hard for me to understand too, but I haven't been able to find a tutorial that did this whilst also including a join statement.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't need dynamic pivot since you know the number of columns beforehand. Dynamic pivot is used when you create columns based on values in table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dynamic pivot for this, in fact you don't even need to use real pivot command, you can easily simulate with CASE and GROUP BY

After retrieving results you showed up there, just assign numbers 1-3 for each row using ROW_NUMBER() function and at the end use that RN to choose what goes into which column.

Here is a snippet, add you real code in first CTE.

```
WITH CTE_Source AS 
(
   --Your query goes here
)
, CTE_RN AS 
(
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceName ORDER BY OutcomeDesc) RN
    FROM CTE_Source
)
SELECT ServiceName
, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN OutcomeDesc END) AS OutcomeDesc1
, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN NewOutcomeDesc END) AS NewOutcomeDesc1
, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN OutcomeDesc END) AS OutcomeDesc2
, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN NewOutcomeDesc END) AS NewOutcomeDesc2
, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN OutcomeDesc END) AS OutcomeDesc3
, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN NewOutcomeDesc END) AS NewOutcomeDesc3
FROM CTE_RN
GROUP BY ServiceName
```

[DEMO using your data as SourceTable](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b2f6/1)